# Adding a second sd card to raspberry pi zero w

Tags: sd-card, pi-zero-w, raspberry-pi-os

I would like to add a second sd card to raspberry pi zero w. Is it possible do that. If it is, how can i do that? I have searched pinout of raspberry pi zero w via google, but i cannot found cs, sck ports.

Comment: Buy a USB SD Card writer they cost < $5

Answer (score 1):

You could add a USB adapter and use the card as disk drive. It will the appear as a block device under /dev/sdx and then you can treat it as a disk drive.

One other way would be to use a small SPI adapter but you will need to make sure it is one that has 3.3v I/O rather than the more common 5v ones.

Depending on where you buy one from they may provide drivers or it may involve a kernel recompile for support.  As such, I would go for the USB adapter if you can manage the footprint.

Details on the SPI can be found at [this website](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi) with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) giving you background on the specification whereas the RPF has [these details](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/).

- CS is chip select and the Pi supports two by default on SPI0 CE0 and SPI0 CE1 allowing two devices on the bus at once.
- SCK should be SCLK or the serial clock and the Pi has this on SPI0 SCLK

On 40pin headers, you can also use the second user set - replace SPI0 with SPI1 and refer to the pin out diagram.  Note this requires Jessie or above.

Being honest - if you are struggling to with matching pin names like this you will do much better to go the USB route and make life simple for yourself.

Comment: I have tried to connect spi adapter but I could not found cs and sck ports as I said in the question.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I did what you said but raspberry doesn't read sd card. Is there any process after that ?

Comment: Lots - see `Depending on where you buy one from they may provide drivers or it may involve a kernel recompile for support`.

Comment: i am using arduino sd card module. Does it create a problem?

Comment: You may have a voltage issue 5v vs 3.3v but TBH I'm stuck to go much further without seeing things and trying things hands on as there are thousands on modules and if it was cheap the module you got may not be the same as advertised.  I would go back to the supplier for support at this point but if it did not say Pi them my guess is voltage - the original link had a voltage converter in it. Even if that is right you then have the software issue as the Pi OS will not support this by default.